# link that open in new window with the size we want in a href

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i create table who has link to post data, then if the link clicked, it will open in new window with the size we want.

here's the code :

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
            {
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['PONumber'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['POdate'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['customername'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['description'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['poqty'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['TotalQtySpb'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['OTSPO'] . "</td>";?>
            <td><?php echo('<a href="index.php?action&ponumber='.$row['PONumber'].'" target="_blank">'."Klik Disini".'</a>');?></td><?php
            echo "</tr>";
            }
```

i tried to modify open in new window by add target="_blank" in a href but its not working (opened in new tab instead in new window)..

tried javascript like this but didnt understand how to apply it in table.

```
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

    <script>
    function myFunction() {
        window.open("http://www.w3schools.com","","width=900,height=300,top=100,left=100" );
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: when you say "it is not working", what do you see? did you check your pop up blockers?

Comment: no reason that `target="_blank"` shouldn't work

Comment: it working but it opened in new tab, not in new window.

Comment: You can't open new window from href. Would need to pass the href to `window.open` and prevent the default click opening new tab

Answer (score 0):

[Something like this](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_fetch_assoc.asp) should get you going (untested, just for e.g.):

**PHP:**

```
$result = do_your_mysqli_query_here;

$out = '';
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    $out .= "<tr>";
    $out .= "<td>" . $row['PONumber'] . "</td>";
    $out .= "<td>" . $row['POdate'] . "</td>";
    $out .= "<td>" . $row['customername'] . "</td>";
    $out .= "<td>" . $row['description'] . "</td>";
    $out .= "<td>" . $row['poqty'] . "</td>";
    $out .= "<td>" . $row['TotalQtySpb'] . "</td>";
    $out .= "<td>" . $row['OTSPO'] . "</td>";
    $out .= '<td><a class="porow" href="#" data-ponumber="'.$row['PONumber'].'" target="_blank">Klik Disini</a></td>';
    $out .= "</tr>";
}
echo $out;
```

**javascript/jQuery:**

```
$(document).on('click', 'a.porow', function(){
    var po = $(this).data('ponumber'); //gets value of data-ponumber for this a tag
    var str = 'http://index.php?action=&ponumber=' + po;
    window.location.href = str;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Can do it this way using jQuery

```
$('td a').click(function(e){
      // prevent browser following link
      e.preventDefault();
      //open in new window
      window.open(this.href,"","width=900,height=300,top=100,left=100" );
});
```

Add a class to elements and update the selector with that class

Comment: can you more specific ? i still tried to understand your answer but me just new in jquery or javascript.

Comment: Charlie means: **(a)** Add a class to the `<a>` tag *(eg: `<a class="galdi" href="index.php?action&ponumber="'.$row['PONumber'].'" target="_blank">`)* and **(b)** use that selector to trap the jQuery click event: `$(document).on('click', '.galdi', function(){ //do the code });`